# mongodb crashes after update due to many connections

Tags: mongodb, updates, connection

I'm writing an update command in mongo on an element inside an array. I am using the `$` operation and `$set`. The array contains 500 elements and we figured out that if we reduce the number of elements to 10 it works, otherwise it crashes with the error `connection refused` which means there are too many connection.
Does mongo open connection for each update using `$` operator? I.e when it go over the array.

```
db.col.update({query},{$set:{arr.$.element:element}})
```

Comment: You should check the ulimits setting in your server: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/ulimit/

Comment: As Lalit says, check the ulimits setting if you're worried about too many connections, but an update with `$` isn't going to be special and open extra connections. The error `connection refused` doesn't a priori mean too many connections, unless there's more context you're not telling us about? We'll need more information, like what the query is, what docs look like, and what the errors are in the logs, to help you further.